# EasyUI $.messager scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the `$.messager` from EasyUI, and everytime I click on the button the dialog displays, but the page scrolls down.

Here is the code im using :

```
$(function () {
    var button = $('.form_button');

    button.click(function(e) {
        var user_id = $(this).attr('user_id');

        $.messager.defaults.ok = 'Yes';
        $.messager.defaults.cancel = 'No';

        $.messager.confirm('Confirm','Are you sure you want to block this user?',function(r){
            if (r){
                alert(user_id);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update** you can get current scroll position by  $(window).scrollTop()

```
var currentPos =  $(window).scrollTop();
$(window).animate({scrollTop:currentPos }, '500');
```

you should use following  in your function when you click that button.
scrollTop will take your window at normal position (when the page was loaded)

```
 $(window).animate({scrollTop:0}, '500');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the framework, as the demos on its home page exhibit the same behaviour. You should file a bug.

Fortunately, you can make several workarounds though. Scrolling to the top may be the easiest, but IMHO that's a UX nightmare. You should calculate the center of the current viewport, and show the window there. Maybe this can be done in CSS too, I am not sure.

Comment: you can get current scroll position by $(window).scrollTop()